# .plist file writing failed! what is wrong with this code?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa, plist, nsmutabledictionary

Nothing is written in my plist file after this code. What is wrong with my code?

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
NSString *finalPath = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"aFile.plist"];
NSMutableDictionary *reqData = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:finalPath];
/*
some modifications to "reqData"
*/
[reqData writeToFile:finalPath atomically:YES];
```

Nothing is written in file. what could be the problem?

Comment: I can read the data from the file. But, I was unable to write anything to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're including the plist with your application, you'll want to copy that file into the Documents directly when the app first starts up (if it hasn't already been copied there). Then, any read and write operations you want to do on the plist should be done from the copy in the Documents directory instead of the version in the app bundle.

Answer (score 2):

You'd better write to Document folder:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
                                                     NSUserDomainMask,
                                                     YES);
NSString *path = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
```

**Update**

According to [NSDictionary Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsdictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDictionary/writeToFile%3aatomically%3a):

> This method recursively validates that all the contained objects are property list objects (instances of NSData, NSDate, NSNumber, NSString, NSArray, or NSDictionary) before writing out the file, and returns NO if all the objects are not property list objects, since the resultant file would not be a valid property list.

Is there any objects with a type other than these valid ones in your whole dictionary?

Comment: Revised my answer... Check whether it's your case?

Comment: Nope, I have just 2 data types: NSNumber and NSDate.

Comment: @DhilipSiva please show your modified code, where you use the document directory. Add a `NSLog(@"filename = '%@'", finalePath);`. `reqData writeToFile` returns a BOOL. What is the value?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to write the file back to the app bundle.

That's what's most likely causing the error.

What if you try writing it somewhere else (e.g. in your desktop folder)?

Comment: actually, that is an iOS app.

Comment: @DhilipSiva OK, have you tried writing the file to **any** other acceptable iPhone location?

Comment: This is the correct response. You can't write to the app bundle. On the Mac, you can get away with it in certain limited circumstances, but you can't safely assume you can do it; on iOS, you can't do it, period.

Answer (score 0):

First Thing to remember:

You can read a plist file from resources but you can't modify it.

if you want to modify,

1. copy that file to Documents directory
2. copy contents of plist into array or dictionary depending on its type
3. make changes you want
4. Finally.... save it back to documents directory

that do the trick